# how does monit every cycle statement works?

Tags: linux, monit

I have a monit check program as follows

```
check program test_pgm with path "/bin/bash /var/run/test.sh"
every 2 cycles
if status !=0 for 2 cycles then alert
```

Let's say my monit daemon is set to run every 60 seconds which means each cycle is 1 minute. I want to run my program every 2mins and alert if it fails twice in a row

Is what I have above correct? or should I say

```
if status !=0 for 4 cycles then alert
```

or should it be

```
if status !=0 for 2 times within 2 cycles then alert
```

Answer (score 0):

`if status !=0 for 2 cycles then alert` seems to be correct. Looks like only the executed cycles are counted.

---

tested with running `monit -d 6 -vI -c ./monit_test_every2.conf`

content of ./monit_test_every2.conf:

```
check program test_pgm with path "/bin/false fail always"
  every 2 cycles
  if status !=0 for 2 cycles then exec "/bin/true alerting"
```

(When your run this as the same user running normal monit, set pid-file and status-file as well.)